# Switching to a 'Main' coroutine and suspending it to send result back to an 'IO' coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When a long running 'IO' coroutine is running, I need to access a view to draw its content onto a canvas at some point of time. I assume that I need to switch to 'Main' coroutine before doing anything about view. And, I, also, assume that I need to wait for view to be able to do its task. I am doing it like this:

```
suspend fun tryBlindFrameBitmap(
    frame: View
) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

    // offscreen work

    createBitmapFromView(frame, calculatedWidth, calculatedHeight)?.let {
        // some bitmap exploration
        bitmap.recycle()
    }

    // offscreen work
}

suspend fun createBitmapFromView(
    view: View,
    width: Int,
    height: Int
): Bitmap? {

    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    bitmap.setHasAlpha(true)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

    return withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {

        suspendCoroutine<Bitmap> { continuation ->

            view.post {
                view.draw(canvas)
                continuation.resume(bitmap)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I feel I am doing something wrong or out of the "best" way. I haven't tested my code yet, will this even work?

How can I improve on this situation?

Answer (score 1):

`suspendCoroutine<Bitmap>` is redundant, `withContext(Main)` has already posted your code to the GUI thread. Also it seems that the return type is needlessly nullable. You can write your function like this:

```
suspend fun createBitmapFromView(view: View, width: Int, height: Int): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            .apply { setHasAlpha(true) }
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        view.draw(Canvas(bitmap))
    }
    return bitmap
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example to this answer, please? I just want to be sure. What I understood is that I would need to create 4 methods. First for pre-work, second for create-bitmap, third for painting and fourth for post-work. Right? First and last are running on IO, second on Default, third on Main. How would you do it?

Comment: Also, do all of them need to be inside a "launch" or a predefined coroutineScope?

Comment: I looked it more closely, it's not convenient to extract these functions.